# git-receive-pack : command not found

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, git, version-control

I made a git repo on a local machine with "git init --bare" and added it as the remote origin on the project on my main computer with ssh:

```
git add remote origin git@192.168.1.14:repoName.git
```

I was able to make a commit and push from my main computer to the other computer the day I created the repo, but today i tried and it didn't work.

When I did "git push origin" it returned this error:

```
bash: line 1: git-receive-pack: command not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The two machines are mac the main one running Leopard and the server one running Tiger. I think it may be realted to the $PATH of git on the server but I'm not sure.

i used theses instrution to create my git server: http://blog.commonthread.com/2008/4/14/setting-up-a-git-server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I solved my problem.

I looks like the probleme was ssh not reading .bash_profile
What I had to do is write

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

in .bashrc instead since ssh reads that file.

Comment: Same applies for OpenIndiana (and most likely other unixes). Placing PATH definition in .bashrc works for git push over ssh.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use /etc/rc.common instead ~/.bashrc to solve these problem for all users and all shells on your server

Answer (score 1):

The standard installation of Git on OS X puts `git` in `/usr/local/git/bin`

The `.bashrc` path statement should look like

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin
```